why my modal has no content but if i reload it has content
this is the home page of my website where the modal doesn't work, can someone answer this bug that I've been encountering for days
<title>Home</title>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



<!-- Alertify sakit sa ulo -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.min.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css"/>



<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/logo.ico">

  <!--

    You may not copy, reproduce, distribute, publish, display, perform, modify, create derivative works, transmit, 

    or in any way exploit any such content, nor may you distribute any part of this content over any network, including a local area network, 

    sell or offer it for sale, or use such content to construct any kind of database. You may not alter or remove any copyright or 

    other notice from copies of the content on AI Tech’s website. 

  -->

<style>

  .thumb {

    display: flex;

    margin-top: -60px;

    justify-content: center;

  }

  .thumb a:hover {

    margin-top: -15px;

    transition: 0.2s;

  }

  .thumb img {

    width: 54px;

    margin: 20px 20px 0 10px;

    max-height: 100%;

  }



   /* Scrollbar*/

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {

    width: 20px;

  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {

    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 

    border-radius: 10px;

  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {

    background: #006341; 

    border-radius: 10px;

  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {

    background: #b30000; 

  }

  /* END OF Scrollbar */



  .navbar {

    background-color: #006341; 

    transition: background-color 0.3s ease; 

  }

  .navbar.blurred {

    background-color: transparent; /* aalisin niya yung background color */

    backdrop-filter: blur(20px); /* then eto papalit, blur effect */

  }

  .nav-link {

    color: white;

    font-weight: 500;

    transition: color 0.3s ease 

  }

  .nav-link.scrolled {

    color: #000000;

    font-weight: 500;

  }

  .nav-link.scrolled:hover {

    color: #006341; 

    font-weight: 500;

  }

  #mugIcon {

    color: white;

    transition: color 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition effect for icon color */

  }



  #mugIcon.scrolled {

    color: #000000; /* Change icon color when scrolled */

  }

  #fruitimage {

    max-width: 100%;

    max-height: 300px; /* Adjust the height as needed */

}

</style>

<!--Navbar-->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg shadow-lg sticky-top" id="navbar">

  <div class="container-sm d-flex justify-content-between" style="width: 100%">



    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style="width: 100vw">

      <div>

        <a href="#"> <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="" style="width: 100px" /></a>

      </div>

      <div>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent">

          <i class="fa-solid fa-mug-hot" id="mugIcon"></i>

        </button>

      </div>

    </div>



    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse container-fluid" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="width: 30vw">

      <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="#">

            Home

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link  " href="#content">

            Product

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link " href="cart.html">

            Cart

          </a>

        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>



  </div>

</nav>

<!--End ti Navbar -->



<!-- MODAL ADD ITEMS -->

<div id="modalContainer"></div>

<!-- END MODAL ADD ITEMSSSSSSSS -->





<!--Banner-->

<div>

  <div class="position-relative">

    <img

      src="./img/banner.jpg"

      class="w-100 img-fluid"

      style="

        height: 50vh;

        object-fit: cover;

        filter: blur(2px);

        filter: saturate(2);

      "

    />

    <section

      class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle text-center text-white"

    >

      <h1 class="text-white h1">Starbucks</h1>

      <p class="lead fst-italic h4">

        <i class="fa-solid fa-quote-left"></i> Find Your Perfect Sip at

        Starbucks! <i class="fa-solid fa-quote-right"></i>

      </p>

      <button class="btn text-white shadow" style="background-color: #006341; transition: background-color 0.3s;"

              onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#004f2d'"

              onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#006341'">



        <a href="#content" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">

          <i class="fa-solid fa-mug-hot"></i> Order Now

        </a>



      </button>

    </section>

  </div>

</div>

<!--End Banner-->



<!---Carousel-->



<div class="container-sm mt-5 my-5 text-center">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mx-auto">

            <img src="img/img1.png" alt="" class="starbucks img-fluid" style="width: 300px; height: 400px; filter: drop-shadow(11px 13px 9px #000000); 

        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(11px 13px 9px #000000); -moz-filter: drop-shadow(11px 13px 9px #000000);" />

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4"></div>

    </div>

</div>



<br>



<div class="container mt-5">

  <div class="row">



    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>



    <div class="col-md-6 my-5">

      <div class="thumb d-flex justify-content-center " >

        <a href="home.html#content">

          <img id="bottom" src="img/thumb1.png" onmouseover="imgSlider('img/img1.png');" />

        </a>

        <a href="home.html#content">

          <img src="img/thumb2.png" onmouseover="imgSlider('img/img2.png');" />

        </a>

        <a href="home.html#content">

          <img src="img/thumb3.png" onmouseover="imgSlider('img/img3.png');" />

        </a>

        <a href="home.html#content">

          <img src="img/thumb4.png" onmouseover="imgSlider('img/img4.png');" />

        </a>



      </div>

    </div>



    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>



  </div>

</div>

<!--End Carousel-->



<hr class="container-sm Sborder border-success mt-5 border-2 opacity-50" />



<!--Hero-->

<section class="container-sm">

  <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center">

    <img

      src="./img/hero.png"

      style="width: 200px; height: 45px"

      alt=""

      class="mt-5 mb-3 img-fluid"

      srcset=""

    />

    <p class="w-75 lead text-secondary fst-italic">

      Starbucks is more than just a coffee shop; it's a community hub where

      people connect over delicious drinks and meaningful moments. With our

      expertly crafted coffees, teas, and snacks, every visit is an

      opportunity to treat yourself to quality and comfort. From our iconic

      lattes to seasonal favorites, there's something for every palate. Join

      us at Starbucks and let's make every sip count.

    </p>

    <!-- <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addProduct"> 

    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" >Add Product</button>

    </a> -->

  </div>

</section>

<!-- End Hero-->



<hr class="container-sm Sborder border-success mt-5 border-2 opacity-50" />



<section class="mt-5">

  <div class="container-sm">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-12 text-center">

        <h1 class="fst-italic">Our Products</h1>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div

      class=" w-100"

      id="content"

    ></div>

  </div>

</section>





<!---Footer-->

<footer class="mt-5 text-white p-3" style="background-color: #006341;">

  <div class="container-sm d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">

    <div class="">

      <h4>AI Tech</h4>

      <h5>CCSIT 210</h5>

      <p>BSIT-3A</p>

      <p>Worksheet 5.5 Database Driven JQuery Web-based Shop</p>

      <p>Submitted to: Sir. Donn Genita </p>

      <ul>

        <li>Dran Leynard Gamoso</li>

      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="">

      <div>

        <img src="./img/top.png" style=" width: 50px; height: 50px;" alt="">

      </div>

      <div>

        <p class="fst-bold">&copy; 2024; J&D</p>



      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</footer>

 <!---End Footer-->



  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    //For navbar

    window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };



    function scrollFunction() {

      if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {

        document.getElementById("navbar").classList.add("blurred");

        const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

        navLinks.forEach(link => link.classList.add("scrolled"));

        document.getElementById("mugIcon").classList.add("scrolled"); // Add scrolled class to the icon

      } else {

        document.getElementById("navbar").classList.remove("blurred");

        const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

        navLinks.forEach(link => link.classList.remove("scrolled"));

        document.getElementById("mugIcon").classList.remove("scrolled"); // Remove scrolled class from the icon

      }

    }

    //end of function for navbarrr



    // For carousel na nag chachange image

    function imgSlider(anything){

      document.querySelector('.starbucks').src = anything;

    }



    alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-right');

    alertify.set('notifier', 'delay', 5);





 /*   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        var customerID = sessionStorage.getItem('customerID');

    

        if (customerID) {

          document.getElementById('customerID').innerText = 'Customer ID: ' + customerID;

        } else {

            console.log('Customer ID not found in sessionStorage'); 

        }

    });

  */





    // para sa modal add product

  //  $(document).ready(function () {

    window.onload = function (){

      $('#modalContainer').load('modal.html');



      $('#total').hide()

      $(".addtocart").click(function () {



          var productId = $(this).data("product-id");

          var productName = $(this).data("product-name");

          var productImage = $(this).data("product-image");

          var productDetail = $(this).data("product-detail");

          var productPrice = $(this).data("product-price");



          //ayaw magpakita yung picture sa modal 

          console.log("Product Image URL:", productImage);

          console.log("Product ID:", productId);

          console.log("Product Name:", productName);

          console.log("Product Image:", productImage);

          console.log("Product Detail:", productDetail);

          console.log("Product Price:", productPrice);



          $("#modalProduct #fruitname").text(productName);

          $("#modalProduct #fruitprice").text("Php " + productPrice);

          $("#modalProduct #fruitdetail").text(productDetail);

          $("#modalProduct #fruitimage").attr("src", "/3rdyr/starbuckz/products/" + productImage); //kelangan pala yunf directory lols my ghad sayang 30 mins



          //FUnction for Increment Button on MOdal product

          $("#increment").click(function () {

              let quantity = parseInt($("#quantity").val());

              quantity += 1; 

              $("#quantity").val(quantity); 

              $('#total').show();

              $('#total').val(productPrice * quantity); 

          });



          //FUnction for Decrement Button on MOdal product

          $("#decrement").click(function () {

              let quantity = parseInt($("#quantity").val());

              if (quantity > 0) {

                  quantity -= 1; 

                  $("#quantity").val(quantity); 

                  $('#total').show();

                  $('#total').val(productPrice * quantity); 

              }

          });



          $('#close').click(function(){

            $('#quantity').val(0);

            $('#total').hide()



            //mahirap na bug requires modern solution reload para di mag double yung Qt sa modal

            setTimeout(function () {

                location.reload();

            }, 10);

          });



          $('#buy').click(function () {

              alertify.success('Item added to cart!');



              var quantity = parseInt($("#quantity").val());

              var total = productPrice * quantity;



              var cartItem = {

                  productId: productId, // Use the productId variable

                  productName: productName,

                  productPrice: productPrice,

                  quantity: quantity,

                  total: total

              };



              // Store the cart item in localStorage

              var cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) || [];

              cartItems.push(cartItem);

              localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));



              // Clear the quantity after adding to cart

              $("#quantity").val(0);



              // Reload the page after a delay (e.g., 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds)

              setTimeout(function () {

                  location.reload();

              }, 2000);

          });





          // Function to display cart items

          function displayCartItems() {

                var cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) || [];

                var cartOutput = "Product Name\tQuantity\tTotal\n";

          }



          // Display cart items when the page loads

          displayCartItems();





      });

    }







    function loadProducts() { 

        $.ajax({

            url: 'fetchProduct.php',

            success: function (data) { 

                if (data.trim() === '') {

                    $('#content').append('<div><p>NO PRODUCTS AVAILABLE</p></div>');

                } else {

                    $('#content').append(data);

                }

            },

            error: function () {

                $('#content').append('<div><p>Error loading products. Please try again later.</p></div>');

            }

        });

    }



    loadProducts();



  </script>

I hosted it online sometimes the modal has content but also sometimes it doesn't,i also tried adding a console.log to determine if the modal is clicked but it doesn't work

You don't explain what is exactly the problem. Edit your question and focus on exact problem or error.

window.onload = function () {
    // Function to load modal content
    function loadModalContent() {
        $('#modalContainer').load('modal.html', function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                // Handle error loading modal content
                console.error("Error loading modal content:", xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
                 }
        });
    }

    // Load modal content when the window is loaded
    loadModalContent();
};


What is it that your code is doing differently than OP's? What benefits does it bring? What problems does it solve? ... Place these explanations in your answer if any.

it doesnt work, it still has no content on my hosted site

As I think <div id="modalContainer"></div> is the modal of your page.
It is loading on the top of your file.
I am suggesting you to use object tag to load your file as follows.


<div id="modalContainer">
 <object type="text/html" data="modal.html"
            style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
 </object>
</div>



Hope this will help you..

this one works, thanks
